# Does mixture of sigmoids make sense given the theories about mixture of bernoullis?

Tags: gaussian-mixture-distribution, mixture-distribution, bernoulli-distribution, sigmoid-curve

Mixture of bernoullis is the combination of bernoulli distributions, which can be illustrated by the sampling process of K bags of D coins, here is a quick tutorial about it https://cedar.buffalo.edu/~srihari/CSE574/Chap9/Ch9.4-MixturesofBernoulli.pdf
Sigmoid functions also give output between 0 and 1, so does it make sense if something called mixture of sigmoids? Is it useful?